# How To capture particular window instead of total desktop?

Tags: com, visual-c++, atl

I have captured total desktop using CPP, COM and DirectShow. But how can I capture particular window only?

Comment: Do you mean capture as in screen shot?

Comment: Not a screen shot, but I have to capture a particular window which can be re size, minimize and publish it on remote end. Also what should be put on remote end when that window gets minimized?

Answer (score 0):

I make use of a few helpers - but those should be easy to translate into what you need:

```
// Copy the contents of the client area or the window into an HBITMAP
HBITMAP CaptureWindow(HWND hwnd, bool bIncludeFrame, const RECT * pClip)
{
    // get the DC of the source
    HDC hdcSource = bIncludeFrame ? ::GetWindowDC(hwnd) : ::GetDC(hwnd);

    // get a memory DC
    HDC hdcMemory = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSource);

    // get the clipping rect
    RECT rcClip;
    if (pClip)
        rcClip = *pClip;
    else if (bIncludeFrame)
        ::GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rcClip);
    else
        ::GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClip);

    // determine the size of bitmap we're going to be making
    SIZE sz = { rcClip.right - rcClip.left, rcClip.bottom - rcClip.top };

    // create a bitmap on which to copy the image
    HBITMAP hbmCapture = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSource, sz.cx, sz.cy);

    // temporarily select our bitmap into the memory DC, grab the image, then deselect it again
    if (AutoSelectGDIObject & select_capture = AutoSelectGDIObject(hdcMemory, hbmCapture))
        ::BitBlt(hdcMemory, 0, 0, sz.cx, sz.cy, hdcSource, rcClip.left, rcClip.top, SRCCOPY);

    // release our resources
    ::DeleteDC(hdcMemory);
    ::ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdcSource);

    // return the captured bitmap
    return hbmCapture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The way you capture desktop, `BitBlt` only the region of the window of interest into your offscreen bitmap (think of capturing full desktop and cropping image to window position)
2. Or, use `WM_PAINT`, `WM_PRINTCLIENT` messages to request the window to paint itself into your `DC`